# Access string's binary in Python

Tags: python, string, binary

I am encoding a string in UTF-8 in Python. I need to access its binary, however I have no idea how. The code bellow shows this:

```
s = 'Hello'.encode('utf-8') #Enconding the UTF-8 string

print(s) #This outputs 'b"Hello"', however I need to access its binary
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you explain more about what you want to do with the bytes?

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit about what you mean by "access".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want binary numbers you can use the `b` format specifier when printing. This example also has padding with zeros as required to be 8 bits long:

```
>>> print(' '.join('{:08b}'.format(byte) for byte in s))
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111
```

Comment: Here is a longer example: `01000010 01101111 01101100 01101100 01101111 01100011 01101011 01110011 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 01000010 01110010 01100101 01111000 01101001 01110100`

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a `bytes` object, you can iterate over the bytes in the object:

```
s = 'Hello'.encode('utf-8')

for b in s:
    print(b)
```

Result:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

Note the values printed are the integer values of each byte in `s`